# Como retirar determinada chave e valor em um dicionário com dados compostos (Keys e Values) no Python?

Tags: python

Fiz um dicionário composto (Keys e Values) **de alquimistas** do anime **Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood** com as seguintes chaves: **Alcunha e Patente** e queria saber **como apagar a chave patente junto com os seus valores de todos os alquimistas armazenados nesse dicionário**.

```
alquimistas = {'Edward Elric': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista de Aço', 'Patente': 'Major'},
               'Alex Louis Armstrong': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista dos Punhos Poderosos', 'Patente': 'Major'},
               'Roy Mustang': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista das Chamas', 'Patente': 'Coronel'},
               'Isaac McDougal': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista de Gelo', 'Patente': 'Major'},
               'Basque Grand': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista de Sangue e Ferro', 'Patente': 'General de Brigada'},
               'Giolio Comanche': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista de Prata', 'Patente': 'Major'},
               'Shou Tucker': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista da Trama Vital', 'Patente': 'Major'},
               'Solf J. Kimblee': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista Rubro', 'Patente': 'Major'},
               'Tim Marcoh': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista de Crista', 'Patente': 'Major'}
              }

print (alquimistas)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa iterar sobre todos os elementos usando `for` e dentro do `loop` usar o `del` para apagar uma determinada chave, veja:

```
for nome in alquimistas:
    del alquimistas[nome]['Patente']
```

Veja funcionando: https://onlinegdb.com/Hkwg3DOj4

Comment: Esse `nome` veio de onde?

Comment: quando você itera sobre um objeto você consegue extrair o `indice` de cada iteração; ou seja o `nome` vai ser sempre o nome do alquimista

Comment: Não retorna nada

Comment: coloquei um teste do código para você ver o resultado

Comment: Faltou colocar o `print (alquimistas)` por isso que o código não retornava nada.

Comment: Dá pra retirar a chave patente de apenas um alquimista?

Comment: sim @AlexF. use o `del` do mesmo modo que mostrei na resposta: `del alquimistas['Edward Elric']['Patente']`

Comment: Teria que colocar `for 'Edward Elric' in alquimistas:
    del alquimistas['Edward Elric']['Patente']` ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93189/discussion-between-rfl-and-alex-f).

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você tem que percorrer todos os alquimistas, e para cada um deles, apagar a chave patente.

Com o `for` você consegue percorrer o dicionário.

Na primeira iteração `alquimista` vai ser `Edward Elric`, depois `Alex Louis Armstrong`, depois `Roy Mustang`, e assim sucessivamente. Para cada um desses alquimistas, você vai ter que deletar a key patente, usando o `del` do `python`.

```
for alquimista in alquimistas:
    del alquimistas[alquimista]["Patente"]
```

Depois disso, se você der print no dicionário de novo

```
print (alquimistas)
```

Vai retornar:

> {'Edward Elric': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista de Aço'}, 'Alex Louis
>   Armstrong': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista dos Punhos Poderosos'}, 'Roy
>   Mustang': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista das Chamas'}, 'Isaac McDougal':
>   {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista de Gelo'}, 'Basque Grand': {'Alcunha':
>   'Alquimista de Sangue e Ferro'}, 'Giolio Comanche': {'Alcunha':
>   'Alquimista de Prata'}, 'Shou Tucker': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista da
>   Trama Vital'}, 'Solf J. Kimblee': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista Rubro'},
>   'Tim Marcoh': {'Alcunha': 'Alquimista de Crista'}}

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: @AlexF. Se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema.